# Dialog won't stay shown on the screen

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The logic seems to be right, there are no errors but my dialog won't stay on for longer than a millisec.
I have to keep clicking dialog button to see it.
Here is the code:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun PermissionHandling(context: Context) {

    val permissionState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
        permissions = listOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)
    )

    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }


    DisposableEffect(key1 = lifecycleOwner, effect = {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) {

                /** Figure out why is permission status not shown when permissions are first set **/

                val job = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    permissionState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()
                    delay(1000L)
                }

                runBlocking {
                    delay(2000L)
                    job.join()
                }
            }
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    })

    permissionState.permissions.forEach { perm ->
        when (perm.permission) {

            Manifest.permission.CAMERA -> {
                when {
                    perm.status.isGranted -> {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context, "Camera permission has been granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }

                    perm.status.shouldShowRationale -> {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Camera permission is needed to upload images",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            }

            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES -> {
                when {
                    perm.status.isGranted -> {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context, "Storage permission has been granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }

                    perm.status.shouldShowRationale -> {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Storage permission is needed to upload images",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (permissionState.allPermissionsGranted) {

        MyDialog(onDismiss = { showDialog = false }, showDialog = showDialog)

    }


}

@Composable
fun MyDialog(
    onDismiss: () -> Unit, showDialog: Boolean
) {

    if (showDialog) {

        Dialog(onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() }, content = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.background(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp), color = Color.White
                )
            ) {

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,

                    ) {
                    Text(text = "Material Dialog")
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    Text(text = "This is a simple Material Dialog.")
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    Button(
                        onClick = { onDismiss() },
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    ) {
                        Text("OK")
                    }
                }

            }

        }, properties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnClickOutside = false, dismissOnBackPress = false
        )

        )
    }


}
```

I tried calling different alert dialogs but the same problem persists.
My guess is library verisons or something in gradle file.

Comment: Well it's obvious your dialog won't show because your `fun MyDialog()` is called inside an if statement block that is not true by default so it won't show and after all permissions are granted then it will be called with the variable `showDialog=false` which will affect the inside if block of `MyDialog` . You should rearrange the way and the logic used to call your `MyDialog` function

Comment: @AymanAit please don't post answers as comments :)

Comment: @LevLeontev Lol i wouldn't say these is an answer especially for a new jetpack compose user + I'm on the phone so I can't give a good answer:)

Comment: @AymanAit But it is shown for a millisec? If that's true, it shouldn't be show at all right?